# Basic Java String using first character and deleting spaces

Tags: java, string, join, indexing, space

The aim of the method is for example the user enters 'John Tom' when asked for user to then take the first letter 'J' put it into string1 which is complete. Then find the index of the space and add the word 'Tom' or whatever else to string2 and then add string1 and string2 together to have username = JTom or whatever other name without any spaces although store the index of the space in pos. So join string1 and string2 but also remove spaces and hold the index in variable 'pos'. If anyone has any tips for me that would be great on the needed code or code that could be improved.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String user;//user variable
    System.out.println("Please enter a name: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
    user = scan.nextLine();//user input for name
    create_name(user);//calls create_name method
}

public static void create_name(String user) {
   String String2;
   int pos = 0;
   pos = user.indexOf(' ');
   String string1 = String.valueOf(user.charAt(0));// 
   System.out.println(string1);
   System.out.println(pos);




 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
System.out.println(string1);
```

Use:

```
System.out.println(string1 + user.substring(pos + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
String result = string1+ user.substring(pos + 1);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Update:**
If there are cases where user will have one or more middle names, I would do:

```
String result1 = string1 + user.substring(user.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
System.out.println(result1);
```

Comment: If the user entered 3 names for example John Tom Jones, how would it take only 'JTom' instead of 'JTom Jones' is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here would probably be the most efficient methods, but you could alternatively separate 'John' from 'Tom' into an array then crop them accordingly:

```
String name = "John Tom";
String[] splitName = name.split(" "); 
System.out.println(splitName[0].charAt(0) + splitName[1]);
```